# Why the result of two different queries have different UI in phpMyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have two queries which have identical output *(however they doesn't have identical order)*. But the result of those two queries have different design. Here is two screenshot of them:

**Query1:**

[image]

**Query2:**

[image]

As you see second query has some tools *(edit, delete, copy)* for each row. Why the first query doesn't has?

---

**EDIT:** Here is those two queries:

**Query1:**

```
(SELECT id, event, seen, time_stamp 
 FROM notifications n
 WHERE id_user = 123 AND seen IS NULL
)UNION
(SELECT id, event, seen, time_stamp
 FROM notifications n
 WHERE id_user = 123 AND seen IS NOT NULL
 LIMIT 2
)UNION 
(SELECT id, event, seen, time_stamp 
 FROM notifications n
 WHERE id_user =  123
 ORDER BY (seen IS NULL) desc, time_stamp desc
 LIMIT 15
)
ORDER BY (seen IS NULL) desc, time_stamp desc;
```

**Query2:**

```
SELECT `id`, `event`, `seen`, `time_stamp`
FROM (SELECT `id`, `event`, `seen`, `time_stamp`, @`unread` := @`unread` + 1
      FROM `notifications`, (SELECT @`unread` := 0) `unr`
      WHERE `id_user` = 123 AND `seen` IS NULL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT `id`, `event`, `seen`, `time_stamp`, @`read` := @`read` + 1
      FROM `notifications`, (SELECT @`read` := 0) `r`
      WHERE `id_user` = 123 AND `seen` IS NOT NULL
            AND (
                 @`read` < (15 - @`unread`) OR
                 ((15 - @`unread`) < 0 AND @`read` < 2)
            )
) `source`
```

Comment: Can you share your queries?

Comment: @Mureinik I've added those two queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that if the system detects that there is only one table, lends you to edit. In your first query is a JOIN of three tables (even being the same table) but the second query gets data directly from one table (that is the result of a join but at the end is for mysql like one table)

It's curious but it seems that works this way

:)

Comment: That's correct .. If I write an outer `SELECT` for first query, then the result will be the same as second one. +1

Comment: Not all that curious, though... there is a proper explanation. [On the wire](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/com-query-response.html#packet-Protocol::ColumnDefinition), the server tells the client which base table table each column in a result set comes from.  With a derived table, as above, the connection back to the base table is lost; there's not a way to trace back to the original row in the original table so the client can't automatically determine what it would mean to "edit" a row, and the UI changes accordingly.